# storing data on sql database vs array (mobile apps)

Tags: android, ios, arrays, sqlite

I have a classifieds app for android. It has a list of 4k
cities with corresponding zip codes stored in a assoc array
like so:

```
Map<String, String> cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
cities.put("Rio", "32433");
cities.put("Buenos Aires", "54335");
```

I am in the process of developing the app for the iphone now,
using swift and I was wondering, whether I should stick with
storing the city data in a array or store it in a database.

Will it make a difference in performance? The app will have
fill the array each time the app is launched, so maybe a database
integration would make the app launch faster and consume less resources.

If anyone has any advice I would highly appreciate it.
Again the list array has about 4k elements/rows.

Comment: It depends on what's in your array. If there's only a few Strings that aren't too long, then I'd say keep it in an array, or use some other container like a queue or stack.

Comment: The strings are pretty much the same length as shown. City names that's it.

Comment: Well how are you loading the names into an array? From a database? From a file?

Comment: Exactly as shown, it's a very long java file :)

Comment: Definitely database for Android. You should try Realm.

Comment: Realm is better than SQLITE? Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a better approach to save such data in database, I'll give following 2 reasons to support this:

1. 4K might not seem a large memory chunk, but consider that each city has 2 objects, city name and zip code, so if there are 1000 cities than you are always keeping 2000 objects in memory!
2. Using database you can dump all the cities info into the database at compile time and there is no startup cost.

Comment: Hi,
What do you mean "if there are 1000 cities that you're always keeping" ?

The data in the array is used to populate the search box. So when a user
searches for a new city a dropdown displays the only available matched city names.
So I don't access 1000 objects at a time. Just one.

Comment: It does not matter if you access the objects or not.. but your java file is adding all the cities to the HashMap, So they will be always retained in memory for the lifetime of that HashMap!

Comment: Your answer's logic lead me to ask this question. It's exactly what I thought, It might be better to dump cities at first launch.

Comment: If I may ask you another question. If the size of the sql dump is 70kb (uncompressed). Will it make any Real difference in loading times? 
I mean  the array would occupy the same amount of memory... Just curious.

Comment: First, When using database you don't event have to dump data on first launch, You can just use a preloaded db file.

Comment: Secondly, Using database, You don't have to fetch all the rows at once, You can use things like CursorAdapter to populate your list view, which would read the data efficiently as needed.